# Airflow webserver `http://0.0.0.0:8080/` not working

Tags: localhost, airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux, airflow-webserver

```bash
$ airflow webserver
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
Access Logformat:
=================================================================
/home/shubham/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_limiter/extension.py:293 UserWarning: Using the in-memory storage for tracking rate limits as no storage was explicitly specified. This is not recommended for production use. See: https://flask-limiter.readthedocs.io#configuring-a-storage-backend for documentation about configuring the storage backend.
[2023-06-19 23:43:25 +0530] [464] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-06-19 23:43:25 +0530] [464] [INFO] Listening at: **http://0.0.0.0:8080** (464)
[2023-06-19 23:43:25 +0530] [464] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-06-19 23:43:25 +0530] [466] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 466
[2023-06-19 23:43:25 +0530] [467] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 467
[2023-06-19 23:43:25 +0530] [468] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 468
[2023-06-19 23:43:25 +0530] [469] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 469
```

In this running http://0.0.0.0:8080 is not working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt1Sm.png)

I tried running it in windows-subsystem-linux using bash and in ubuntu by downloading `$ wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb $ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` in ubuntu and tried to open the `$ xdg-open http://0.0.0.0:8080` through ubuntu terminal in windows subsystem and tried to run docker-container also after failure but still it didn't work.

Comment: don't use `0.0.0.0`. Use `127.0.0.1`, or `localhost` or another address of your computer

Comment: I didn't use that, Apache-Airflow told me to click on that as my server was in there as per AIRFLOW.

Comment: I don't know if this is still true, but at one point WSL had a seperate IP for `localhost` that could not be reached from the "Windows side".  I remember having to set up some kind of special forwarding rules to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use `http://localhost:8080/` instead of `http://0.0.0.0:8080/`.

And I can't believe how simple the answer can be, and I found this answer nowhere; just a mere coincidence that I was watching a YouTube tutorial on running airflow using docker, and the guy used `http://localhost:8080/` instead of `http://0.0.0.0:8080/` without any reason. Then I realized what the problem was. I want the @apache team to look into this because this simple thing took a whole day to figure out. I know it's very rear, but it's real.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6UnA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this http://localhost:8080/home, let me know if it doesnt work

Comment: Yup, I figured it out on my own after I wasted my whole day. This was for those who may get this problem cause no answer was available in the internet.

Comment: Thanks , You can actually tick the answer so that people will know ! @ShubhamVerma